# Spark 2.4 drop columns based on value scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, filter

I am using spark 2.4 with scala 2.11 ,I want to drop column from df having value "Default" and zero.

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
|A      |B       |C          | D     |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
|     1 |      1 |   Deafult |  0    |   
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

This is what I'm expecting as an output:

```
+-------+--------+
|A      |B       |
+-------+--------+
|     1 |      1 |  
+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

With your example, which has only one record in the dataframe:

```
// Get values as an array, mapping to true/false depending on whether it's the default
val dfValues = df.head.toSeq.map(v => v == 0 || v == "Default")

// Get column names that are not default
val columns = (df.columns zip dfValues)
                .collect { case (col, isDefault) if !isDefault => col }
                .map(col)

// Read selected columns
df.select(columns:_*)
```

If you have more records in your df you need to specify behavior first (should a column be included if there any value is non-default? All values non-default?) and run some aggregation.